# Copy a multi-dimentional array by Value (not by reference) in PHP

Tags: php, copy, multidimensional-array

Language: PHP

I have a form which asks users for their educational details, course details and technical details. When the form is submitted the page goes to a different page to run processes on the information and save parts to a database. **HOWEVER**(!) I then need to return the page back to the original page, where having access to the original post information is needed.

I thought it would be simple to copy (by value) the multi-dimensional (md) $_POST array to $_SESSION['post']

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['post'] = $_POST;
```

However this only appears to place the top level of the array into $_SESSION['post'] not doing anything with the children/sub-arrays.

An abbreviated form of the md $_POST array is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [formid] => 2
    [edu] => Array
        (
            ['id'] => Array
                (
                    [1] => new_1
                    [2] => new_2
                )

            ['nameOfInstitution'] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 2
                )

            ['qualification'] => Array
                (
                    [1] => blah 
                    [2] => blah
                )

            ['grade'] => Array
                (
                    [1] => blah
                    [2] => blah 
                )

        )

    [vID] => 61
    [Submit] => Save and Continue
)
```

If I echo $_SESSION['post']['formid'] it writes "2", and if I echo $_SESSION['post']['edu'] it returns "Array". If I check that edu is an array (is_array($_SESSION['post']['edu])) it returns true. If I echo $_SESSION['post']['edu']['id'] it returns array, but when checked (is_array($_SESSION['post']['edu]['id'])) it returns false and I cannot echo out any of the elements.

How do I successfully copy (by value, not by reference) the whole array (including its children) to an new array?

**THANKS EVERYONE FOR RESPONDING - UPDATE**
The issue was caused my irrelevant quote marks in the naming of fields in my form.

Comment: dont use echo , 
use print_r() instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if this is your real print_r output, then you have some unwanted chars in your array keys.

```
Array
(
    [formid] => 2
    [edu] => Array //<--- $_SESSION['post']['edu']
        (
            ['id'] => Array // <---- $_SESSION['post']['edu']["'id'"]
```

Comment: Thanks Rufinus - in the form the name I'd assigned to the field contained the quote marks - I have taken these out and now it seems to work properly now!

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell why this wouldn't work

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['post'] = $_POST;
```

On the 2nd page, do you call `session_start()` before accessing `$_SESSION`?

You could place this directly under `session_start()` to help debug.

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Comment: Yes I had got session_start() called. The error was caused by quote marks in the name of the field names. Thanks for responding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use serialize () to convert the array to a string and either pass it by post or store it in the session.

I've noticed funny behaviour before in saving an array to $_SESSION in PHP.  Sometimes if you make a reference and use that it's easier, for example:

```
$session =& $_SESSION['post'];

$session = array ();
```

Don't ask why though :)

Also, to expand on what haim evgi said in the comment, wrap the print_r in `<pre>` tags such as:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r ($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

to make the array output readable.

Answer (score 1):

DCD is on the right track.

Generally, I would store a serialized version of the form in the session and then unserialize it when I needed to use it.

To store it:

```
$_SESSION['post'] = serialize($_POST);
```

To retrieve it:

```
$post = unserialize( $_SESSION['post'] );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `echo` in arrays, PHP will print "Array" instead of the array contents. Use `print_r` instead.

Your assignment only looks like it its by reference. Internally (to preserve memory) it is a reference until you change `$_SESSION['post']`. From that point onward, you will have two separate variables.